# Convert n number of rows to columns repeatedly using awk

Tags: awk, csh, gawk

My data is a large text file that consists of 12 rows repeating. It looks something like this:

```
{
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
}
```

repeating over and over. I want to turn every 12 rows  into columns. so the data would look like this:

```
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
```

I have found some examples of how to convert all the rows to columns using awk: `awk '{printf("%s ", $0)}'`, but no examples of how to convert every 12 rows into columns and then repeat the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%12?OFS:RS)}' file
```

`NR%12` evaluates to true except when the record number is exactly divisible by 0. When it is true, the output field separator is used (which defaults to a space). When it is false, the record separator is used (by default, a newline).

Testing it out:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%12?OFS:RS)}' file
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me. It was very helpful. I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idiomatic way (read golfed down version of [Tom Fenech's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25901483/970195) answer)  of doing it with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%12?FS:RS)}1' file
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
```

`ORS` stands for Output Record Separator. We set the `ORS` to `FS` which by default is space for every line except the 12th line where we set it to `RS` which is a newline by default.

Comment: Thanks for the help the code works great. Its always good to learn a few different ways of doing things.