# awk - remove CR or LF from field prior to adding to array

Tags: awk

In reference to this [question regarding column to row transposition using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621457/how-to-transpose-a-repeating-set-of-rows-to-columns-using-awk) I am baffled as to why Ive been unable to display the last column in a row and I suspect the CR from the end of the row is being added to the array to print.

As this appears to be the case as per [the linked question on DOS endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) how do I remove the CR from the last field in the context of the awk script presently being used (without running something like dos2unix):

```
{ 
         if (!keys[$3]++) { b[++c] = $3; row1 = row1 OFS $3; row2 = row2 OFS $4 }
         line = groups[$1][$3];
         groups[$1][$3] = (line == ""? $6$7: line OFS $6$7) 
     }
     END{ 
         print row1 ORS row2; 
         for (i in groups) {
             r = i; 
             for (j in b) r = r OFS groups[i][b[j]];
             print r 
         } 
     }
```

The column with suspected CR is $7, eg

```
22405   XRJ27   IL17C       rs4673      C______2038_20  N   N
22405   XRJ27   CRP     rs2794520   C____177486_10  T   T
22405   XRJ27   G6PC2       rs560887    C____323082_10  C   C
22405   XRJ27   TCN2        rs1801198   C____325467_10  G   G
22405   XRJ27   SLC30A8     rs13266634  C____357888_10  C   C
22405   XRJ27   COL5A1      rs12722     C____370252_20  C   C
22405   XRJ27   LEPR        rs1137100   C____518168_20  A   G
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: confirmed that it is the DOS ending issue and it can be addressed by a tool such as dos2unix - however it would be useful if this could be done in awk

Comment: the linked question does show using `sub` as well within awk... try it...

Comment: Perhaps by specifying on the command line or BEGIN section that RS is '\r\n'?

Comment: @ReluctantBIOSGuy great idea! I would even go for `\r?\n` in case the file is the result of copy pasting from several unix/dos files. So some might have the `\r` and others not.

Comment: @ReluctantBIOSGuy good point.. however that'll require `gawk`.. this is explained as well in the linked question..

Comment: The OP is already using gawk, see her gawk-only array syntax (`groups[$1][$3]`)

Comment: @kvantour files that use `\r\n` (carriage-return linefeed) for the newline often have `\n` (linefeed) alone in the middle of fields. If you use `\r?\n` as the RS value then you can't separate the mid-field linefeeds from the linefeeds that are part of the newline so YMMV with using that and it'd be gawk-only (which the OP does just happen to be using). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks a lot. for some reason I never realised that `RS` in posix only picks the first character and is not a BRE. Apparently to much gnu on my side ;-)